# Why my app is taking too long to be installed?

Tags: java, android, performance

I am developing a new android app. But It's taking very long to be installed. But it's not any device issues, almost all devices taking long time.

Please could you tell me any common problems and solutions. I would be very happy to share any details to get rid of this problem.

Comment: This should happen only first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps sometimes do take a lot of time to get installed. This is primarily due to the size of the app. If the issue is size of the final apk, you can use `splits` or `resConfigs` in your gradle to reduce the app size.

**ResConfigs**

```
 defaultConfig {
 // ...
 resConfigs "en"
 resConfigs "nodpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi"
}
```

**Splits**

```
android {
 ...
splits {

// Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
density {

// Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
enable true

// Specifies a list of screen densities Gradle should not create multiple APKs for.
exclude "ldpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi" // Exclude what you don't require
}}}
```

You can also use the `shrinkResources true` options to reduce the size.

However sometimes small apps also may take lot of time to get installed. This happens when the app has several layouts/activities and drawables. They are basically resources which are compressed in an APK and get extracted during installation. Other than that, the issue would be only in the phone.